# How to leave out chapter numbers in section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

So, I'm writing my thesis using the `book` class. I have the following:

```
[Chapter I The fundamentals]
```

using

```
\chapter{The fundamentals}
```

together with

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

Now, when I define the first section using

```
\section{LIBOR interest rates}
```

I get

```
[I.1 LIBOR interest rates]
```

What I want is for the chapter number to be left out of section numbering. What I want is

```
[1 LIBOR interest rates]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I keep seeing this, but I disagree. Programmers who program in C++ and Java get to earn rep here, why should I have to earn rep here for Perl and there for LaTeX (and what do I do about PerlTeX?) there is plenty of space for LaTeX as a programming language here!

Comment: @Joel: but this isn’t about earning rep. The reputation is just a marketing trick to keep you using Stack Overflow. This is about getting good results and this in turn means turning to the professionals. And TeX.SE certainly has more active TeX users than Stack Overflow, and since there are no other questions, individual questions are harder to miss and the chance that they are answered are greater. My recommendation was thus for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @Joel: In fact, the reason why TeX.SE was founded in the first place was that many TeX questions went unanswered on Stack Overflow because they were lost amidst the sea of other questions.

Comment: @All -- First time I've seen an explanation of the SO/TeX.SE divide... is there a way to push all TeX on SO to TeX.SE?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077833/latex-how-to-leave-out-chapter-numbers-in-section-numbering?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 35):

The solution is completely analogous to your `\thechapter` redefinition:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

(Notice that I’ve used `\renewcommand*` instead of `\renewcommand`. The effect is almost identical but this leads to more comprehensive error messages in some cases. And I’ve omitted the parentheses about `\thesection`. Putting them is fine, too.)

Answer (score 2):

I would try the [`anonchap`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/anonchap.html) or [`fncychap`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/fncychap.html) packages from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/). One of the great things about a mature system like LaTeX is that almost all problems have been solved before. CTAN is a great resource, check it out for things like this.