# Memoir, section numbers without the chapter number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to leave out chapter numbers in section numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44826/how-to-leave-out-chapter-numbers-in-section-numbering)

I'm setting a book with `memoir`. For sections (and below) I get the chapter number, plus the section (or sub-. etc.) number, thus:

```
1.1  My section
```

Is there a way to leave out the chapter number (both in the text and TOC), so as to have this?

```
1.  My section
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` -- this *must* have been answered before.

Comment: Thanks, could you change it to an answer, please?

Comment: Let my look for a possible "original"  question first. ;-)

Comment: Just to be sure: Section numbers will still start at 1 in every chapter. Is this what you want, or do you want continuous section  numbering?

Comment: That's what I want.

Comment: Then I found an original. :-) Note that the problem is not related to `memoir`.